# Saxon .net how handle external resources xml

Tags: c#, .net, saxon

I have a batch and want to rebuild this in a .net application. How can I handle this in .net?

```
-xsl:"style.xsl" resource-path="%runtimepath%%respath%" srcAutotexte="%runtimepath%%respath%\autotext\autotext.xml"
```

My attempt. How can I include the autotext.xml?

```
        // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
        XsltCompiler compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
        compiler.BaseUri = new Uri(styleXslFilePath);
        XsltTransformer transformer = compiler.Compile(File.OpenRead(styleXslFilePath)).Load();
```

Comment: What is the first code snippet, showing how parts of how you call Saxon 9 from the command line? Are `srcAutotexte` and `resource-path` parameters of your stylesheet `style.xsl`? What is the question about, do you only need to know how to set up global parameters when using Saxon in your C# code?

Comment: Parameters can be set with http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XsltTransformer.html#SetParameter(Saxon.Api.QName,Saxon.Api.XdmValue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line options

```
 resource-path="%runtimepath%%respath%"
 srcAutotexte="%runtimepath%%respath%\autotext\autotext.xml"
```

set the values of stylesheet parameters in the transformation.

The equivalent when using the Saxon.Api interface is to call

```
    transformer.SetParameter(
         new QName("resource-path"), 
         new XdmAtomicValue("%runtimepath%%respath%"));
```

etc.

(Perhaps your shell interprets %xxxx% as a reference to a shell/system variable of some kind - it's a long time since I wrote batch scripts under Windows. If that's the case then you'll need to get hold of the values of these variables. You can do that at the C# level using the .NET API, or you might be able to do it from within XSLT 3.0 using the environment-variable() function.)